# Remove node from xmlDoc, how to delete the parentNode?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0

I have an xmlDoc, this is a part of it:

```
<Main>
<Set>
    <MId>1</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>  
<Set>
    <MId>1</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 2
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
<Set>
    <MId>1</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 3
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
<Set>
    <MId>2</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
</Main>
```

By selecting an prdctName the rest has to be removed from the xmlDoc. For example if I choose for "Test 1"
the result has to be:

```
<Main>
<Set>
    <MId>1</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>  
<Set>
    <MId>2</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
</Main>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to remove the  tag. 
So after a remove the xml looks now like:

```
<Main>
<Set>
    <MId>1</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
<Set/>
<Set/>
<Set>
    <MId>2</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
</Main>
```

Which code do I have to write to delete the  tag also?

This is a part of the code I use now:

```
foreach (XmlNode chkNode in nodes)
{                
            string currentName = "Test 1";
            if (!nameDict.ContainsKey(currentName))                                    
                    chkNode.ParentNode.RemoveAll();
}
```

Comment: In your last XML example, I assume the occurance of `</Set></Set></Set>` should actually be `</Set><Set></Set>`?

Comment: Of course there has to be an </Main> tag. There is when I was editing this question but it's gone after I saved the question.

Comment: No </Set></Set></Set> is what I get and this is right. The first one is for the first <Set> tag the other 2 are from the deleted nodes.

Comment: The `</Set></Set></Set>` can never be right because that won't produce a valid XML.

Comment: Sorry it must be <Set/> of course for the two deleted nodes.

Comment: what is `nodes`?  Is it a collection of `XmlNodes` with specific tags?  Or just a collection of all nodes in the XML?  And are you open to other alternatives like `LINQ-to-XML` for your solution?

Comment: FYI - I changed your title based on the fact that it has been discussed and decided that titles should not include `tag` information.  I also added the appropriate `C#-2.0` tag to the question.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/182513

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue is the `XmlNode.RemoveAll()` only removing the children of the node and the  `chkNode.ParentNode` property is selecting the node with the `<Set>` tag. So when you remove all children, you are left with an empty `<Set/>` node.  You need to be able to remove that specific node as well.

To adapt your existing method, you need to do something like:

```
foreach (XmlNode chkNode in nodes)
{                
    string currentName = "Test 1";
    if (!nameDict.ContainsKey(currentName))
    {
        XmlNode parent = chkNode.ParentNode;
        parent.ParentNode.RemoveChild(parent);
    }
}
```

Of course, I can't test this as-is since I am not sure what exactly `nameDict` and `nodes` are.

For the sake of completeness, this code will break if `chkNode` or `chkNode.ParentNode` are `XmlNodes` that cannot have parents (such as a Attribute, Document, DocumentFragment, Entity, Notation nodes). If you think this is a possible scenario, you might want to include the appropriate null checks or wrap this method in a `try-catch`

Something like:

```
XmlNode parent = chkNode.ParentNode;
if (parent != null && parent.ParentNode != null)
    parent.ParentNode.RemoveChild(parent);
```

Or:

```
try
{
    XmlNode parent = chkNode.ParentNode;
    parent.ParentNode.RemoveChild(parent);
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
    // do something with exception
}
```

There are several options with LINQ to accomplish what you want in a better way, but since you are using C#2.0, this solution should get you in the right direction.

Comment: nameDict is just a Dictionary with names that doesn't has to be removed. Nodes is an selection of nodes I have, so in this example all the <Set> nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with help of linq to xml and xpath. Find example below:

```
    var xdocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
    xdocument.Document.Root.Elements()
   .Where(element 
       => !element.XPathSelectElement("RName/MetaData/PrdctName").Value.Contains("Test 1"))
   .Remove();
   // saving results...
   xdocument.Save("somewhere.xml");
```

PS

Not so good to check on contains `Value.Contains("Test 1")`but here don't see any others solutions for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this..

1) read the  tag and copy all child node using inner xml.

2) now go to the root node that is MainParents.

3) now replace the inner xml string with your xml string which is read in first step.